# Calculating employee pay using pass by reference and function overloading

Tags: c++

I have not done so well on an assignment for school - I have submitted what is below and I would like to learn and understand more about why my code is terrible lol.

[The grading criteria is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnvqX.png)

As you can tell, I did not do well at all. I am getting a few errors all related to **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments**. One of the requirements is using pass by reference. When I attempted that, I had many more errors - so I decided to take it back to something a bit simpler for me and I still cannot see what I am doing wrong.

My instructor specified which parameters we needed to use so I am using those specific ones for each function. The other criterion in writing is below as well as my code.

**Again, yes this was for a school assignment, I've already submitted it and got a terrible grade. I would like to have an understanding of what I did wrong and how to correct it so I can learn. Thank you for any and all help.**

> The weekly gross pay of a salaried employee is calculated by dividing
> the employee’s annual salary by 52. Create a named constant variable
> to hold  and use the value in your overloaded function.
>
> • The weekly gross pay of an Hourly employee is calculated as follows:
> If the  number of hours worked by the employee is 40 hours or less,
> the gross pay is  calculated by multiplying the number of hours worked
> by the pay rate. If the  number of hours worked by the employee
> exceeds 40 hours, the employee will  receive regular pay for the first
> 40 hours, and receive time-and-a-half pay for  the hours in excess of
> 40. An hourly employee must not work more than 50  hours per week.
>
> • The weekly gross pay of an intern is calculated by multiplying the
> number of  hours worked by the pay rate. If an intern works over 15
> hours a week, the  intern receives time-and-a-quarter pay for the
> hours over 15 hours. An  intern must not work more than 20 hours per
> week.
>
> • The weekly gross pay of a contract employee is calculated by
> multiplying the  number of hours worked by the pay rate. A contract
> employee must not work  more than 40 hours per week.
>
> Create four overloaded functions (one each for salaried employee,
> hourly employee, contract employee, and Intern) as follows:
>
>  For the Salaried employee function, prompt for two values (employee
> number and yearly salary), and pass these two values to the
> appropriate function.
>
>  For the Hourly employee function, prompt for three values (employee
> number, hours worked and pay rate), and pass these three values to the
> appropriate function.
>
>  For the Intern function, prompt for four values (Institution Code,
> Department  Code, hours worked and pay rate), and pass these four
> values to the appropriate function.
>
> • For the Contract employee function, prompt for five values (company
> number, project number, employee number, hours worked and pay rate),
> and pass these five values to the appropriate function.
>
> For any employee, if more hours than the employee is allowed to work
> (based on  the type of employee) is entered for number of hours,
> reject the input as invalid input, and repeatedly prompt for the valid
> range of hours for the employee type  until the correct information is
> entered.
>
> Continue to request, calculate and display employee information until
> there is no  more employee data to process. The information displayed
> must include all the information collected for each employee and the
> calculated weekly pay. Use the  end-of-file indicator to terminate
> input.
>
> Your program must be able to process zero employees, to an infinite
> number of employees. When the program starts, if there is no data to
> process during this  processing cycle, immediately use the end-of-file
> indicator to terminate  processing, and display an appropriate
> message.
>
> Demonstrate the use of the following in your solution:
>
> • Iteration (Looping)
>
> • Modularity (using functions)
>
> • Function Overloading (use overloaded functions for calculating Gross
> Pay)
>
> • Function Prototyping (create a function prototype for each of the
> overloaded functions)
>
> • Inter-function communication. To demonstrate inter-function
> communication, all prompts for input must occur in the function
> main(), all calculated gross pay amounts must be explicitly returned
> to the function main(), and all output must be displayed by the
> function main(). No output can be displayed by the functions.
>
> • Use of pass-by-reference using Reference arguments. There must be,
> at least, one  example of pass-by-reference using Reference arguments
> with each function in the  program, except main(). Your program,
> depending on the argument(s) supplied by the user, should invoke the
> appropriate overloaded function.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double grossPay(int number, double hours, double pay); // hourly function
double grossPay(int number, double salary); // salary function
double grossPay(int company, int project, int number, double hours, double pay);  // contract function
double grossPay(int institution, int department, double hours, double pay); // intern function


int main() {
    // prompt user for type of employee and give EOF instructions.
    cout << "Enter '1' for hourly. Enter '2' for salaried." << endl;
    cout << "Enter '3' for contracter. Enter '4' for intern." << endl;
    cout << "If result is -1, the input was invalid, please input correct employee hours." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Terminate input by using <ctrl> z on Windows then press enter." << endl;
    cout << "Terminate input by using <ctrl> z on UNIX / Linux / Mac OS X then press enter." << endl;

    int employeeType{ 0 };

    int employeeNumber{ 0 };
    double grossPay{ 0 };
    double overtimePay{ 0 };

    // salaried
    double employeeSalary{ 0 };

    // hourly
    double hoursWorked{ 0 };
    double payRate{ 0 };

    // contractor
    int companyNum{ 0 };
    int projectNum{ 0 };

    // intern
    int schoolCode{ 0 };
    int departmentCode{ 0 };

    while (cin >> employeeType) {

        switch (employeeType) {
        case 1:
            // HOURLY employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of employee including overtime, is $" << grossPay(employeeNumber, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 2:
            // SALARIED employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter employees salary: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of employee" << employeeNumber << "is $" << grossPay(employeeNumber, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 3:
            // CONTRACT employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter company number: " << endl;
            cin >> companyNum;
            cout << "Enter project number: " << endl;
            cin >> projectNum;
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of contractor is $" << grossPay(companyNum, projectNum, employeeNumber, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 4:
            // INTERN prompts and output
            cout << "Enter institution code: " << endl;
            cin >> schoolCode;
            cout << "Enter department code: " << endl;
            cin >> departmentCode;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of intern $" << grossPay(schoolCode, departmentCode, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;
        }

        cout << "Enter '1' for hourly. Enter '2' for salaried." << endl;
        cout << "Enter '3' for contracter. Enter '4' for intern." << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for using this program. " << endl;

}



// hourly function
double grossPay(int number, double hours, double pay) {
    double hourlyWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 50.00) {
        if (hours > 40.00) {
            hourlyWeek = ((pay * 40.00) + (hours - 40.00) * (pay * 1.50));
        }

        else {
            hourlyWeek = (hours * pay);
        }
    }

    while (hours > 50.00) {
        hourlyWeek = -1;
    }

    return hourlyWeek;
}

// salary function
double grossPay(int number, double salary) {
    double salaryWeek{ 0 };

    salaryWeek = (salary * 40);

    return salaryWeek;
}


//contractor function
double grossPay(int company, int project, int number, double hours, double pay) {
    double contractWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 40.00) {
        contractWeek = ((pay * 40.00) + (hours - 40.00) * (pay * 1.50));
    }


    while (hours > 40.00) {
        contractWeek = -1;
    }

    return contractWeek;

}

// intern function
double grossPay(int institution, int department, double hours, double pay) {
    double internWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 20.00) {
        if (hours > 15.00) {
            internWeek = ((pay * 40.00) + (hours - 40.00) * (pay * 1.25));
        }

        else {
            internWeek = (hours * pay);
        }
    }

    while (hours > 20.00) {
        internWeek = -1;
    }

    return internWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename your local variable:

```
double grossPay{ 0 };
```

because you cannot let your variables and function have the same name (grossPay)

by default, the compiler would use virable instead of the method, that's why you got the mistake :)